# django return objects by selection value

Tags: django, filter, selection

I have two models:

```
class Room(models.Model):
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    room_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    room_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

class RoomLog(models.Model):
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room)
    roomlog_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add= True)
    roomlog_value = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

each Room has got multiple related RoomLogs.
for each Room every time Room.room_value is edited & save a new RoomLog object is created.

In Django templates I have a list of unique edits dates.
I would like to click on a date and return for each Room a value that is maximum in a range 'less of equal' selection date.

### How can I achieve it in django ?

The way I have done it so far:

**in template I place:** 
search form:

```
<form method='GET' action=''>
<input type='text' name='q' placeholder='Select date'/>
<input type='submit' value='Select'/>
</form>
```

**and my view**:

```
def main_view(request):
    query = request.GET.get("q")

    if query:
        queryset_list = RoomLog.objects.filter(created_date__lte = query)
        print queryset_list

    return render(request,'template.html', context)
```

so, in this way I can filter RoomLogs BUT I do not return max RoomLog for each Room at the moment and it is something I need to work out furhter.

Comment: You want to click a date and get Rooms or RoomLogs?

Comment: if selected date is less or equal TODAY then for each room return related roomlog_value attribute of the roomlog selected from all related room roomlogs which attribute 'roomlog_date' is maximum date less or equal selected date.

Comment: e.g. Room has got RoomLog1, RoomLog2, RoomLog3 and RoomLog1.roomlog_date is 2016_01_01, RoomLog2.roomlog_date is 2016_02_02, RoomLog3.roomlog_date is 2016_03_03. So, if you select DATE 2016_02_20 then you want to return RoomLog2.roomlog_value for this Room.